Is the current distribution/spread in an AC signal the same as that in an 'alternating DC' signal?
I am trying to understand if -regarding the spreading of the return currents- a polarity-alternating voltage will have the same behavior as a "pulsating" DC voltage (that only has one direction)? Those two signals essentially:

Because in all documents I have seen, the author talks about AC voltage or mentions the frequency used for the simulation, but none of them really mentioned the voltage waveform and the voltage span. An example would be this article. It mentions frequency and talks about good PCB layout techniques.
Now, when I tried to simulate it myself, in matlab, there is no way of defining the voltage span/range, only the frequency. But I get expected results:
mytrace = traceLine;
mytrace.Width = 0.0007; %0.0002
mytrace.Corner = "smooth";
sectorLength = 0.009; %0.005
midseclen = sectorLength*2
mytrace.Length = [sectorLength midseclen sectorLength];
mytrace.Angle  = [0 270 180];
pcb = pcbComponent;
d = dielectric('FR4');
groundplane = traceRectangular('Length', sectorLength*3,'Width',midseclen*2,'Center',[sectorLength/2,-midseclen/2]);
d.Thickness = 0.0009;
pcb.BoardThickness = d.Thickness;
pcb.Layers = {mytrace,d,groundplane};
pcb.BoardShape = groundplane;
pcb.FeedDiameter = mytrace.Width;
pcb.FeedLocations = [0,0,1,3;0,-midseclen,1,3];

figure;
show(pcb)
figure;
current(pcb,10000);%10kHz
figure;
current(pcb,500e6);%500MHz
figure;
current(pcb,1e9);%1GHz


So from all the above I assume either of the plots I first mentioned, will have the same result in the return currents. I would like this assumption to be backed up by the mathematical approach (if its simple enough to be posted or someone has a source of it), or by a simulation result that you can input the voltage range of the singnal.

The current density cannot be the same at the peaks; compare the positive peak.

@Andyaka wait you are right, I didnt define my question properly, I meant to say the "spread of current density", not the maximum/minimum current. I will edit my question

This is a linear system, so the "alternating DC" signal can be treated as a superposition of a DC voltage of 2.5 V and an AC signal with 2.5 V amplitude. Then the return current of the DC component will flow as DC return currents do (direct from one one point to another in your design) and the return current of the AC component will flow as AC return currents do (increasingly concentrated below the trace as the frequency rises).
